# KeySelect via Not[StringMatchQ[Pattern]] fails

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

I have an `Association` `asc` that has mixed type `Keys`:

```
asc = <|"b1" -> 2, "a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|>;
```

I try to select based on excluding a string pattern via `Not @ StringMatchQ` but without succes:

```
KeySelect[asc, ! StringMatchQ["b" ~~ __?DigitQ]]

(* <||> *)
```

The selection based on `StringMatchQ` by itself does work, but I get the  warning that a `String` was expected as `Key` for the third association:

```
KeySelect[asc, StringMatchQ["b" ~~ __?DigitQ]]

(* 
StringMatchQ: String or list of strings expected ....
<|"b1" -> 2|> 
*)
```

I would like to understand:

1. how do I avoid this error message
2. what is wrong with the attempt using `Not @ StringMatchQ`?

Comment: Take a look at: `(! StringMatchQ["any"])@"any" // FullForm`

Comment: @Kuba, it took me a while to understand this and why the original construct would not work, but this improved my understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
KeySelect[Or[Not@StringQ@#, Not@StringMatchQ["b" ~~ DigitCharacter ..]@#] &][asc]
```

> <|"a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|>

Alternatively:

```
KeySelect[Nand[StringQ@#, StringMatchQ["b" ~~ __?DigitQ]@#] &]@asc
```

> <|"a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|>

```
KeySelect[MatchQ[Except[_String] |
    _String?(Not@*StringMatchQ["b" ~~ DigitCharacter ..])]]@asc
```

> <|"a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|>

```
KeySelect[MatchQ[_String?(Not@*StringMatchQ["b" ~~ DigitCharacter ..])]]@asc
```

> <|"a1" -> 1|>

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sander, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.